# react error this.linkState is not a function

Tags: reactjs

There is some url was removed to get the needed libraries, but don't know why this error appears `this.linkState` is not a function?

What can i do, please help

```
render: function() {
  var total = parseInt(this.state.payment, 10) + parseInt(this.state.payment2, 10)
  return (
    <div>
      <Payment valueLink={this.linkState('payment')} />
      <Payment valueLink={this.linkState('payment2')} />
      {total}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Where you have defined `linkState` in this class ?

Answer (score 2):

Now new standard React not support Mixin. If you need in 2-way binding use lib: `react-link-state`